# How to open items one by one

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
    }
```

When I press the `button3` all textboxes open.
 But I want them to open one by one.

Comment: you want to open textBox3 with the first click on button3 and then textBox4 on the second click on that button?

Comment: @WolfgangRoth yes

Comment: try using a counter, to count the clicks. the `int counter` should be declared outside of your method on class level. Then switch the buttons dependent on the counter number

Comment: so you could check if one of the textboxes is visible, and if not activate it...:
if (!textBox3.Visible) 
textBox3.Visible = true;else if (!textBox4.Visible)
textBox4.Visible = true; else if (!textBox5.Visible)
textBox5.Visible = true;

Comment: @WolfgangRoth Also How i can make it with using "if."

Comment: `textBox3.Visible` is a bool variable, so you can check it directly in the if clause. do you know how to write an IF-clause?

Comment: @Mong Zhu Yes, thanks!

Comment: Append all textboxes to a collection like `List<TextBox>` and after it in click handler increment some iteration variable and show i`st element of the `List<TextBox>`

Comment: @EgoPingvina You can give an example?

Comment: please try to implement one of the suggested solutions, then post the code and we will help you to find also others. Since you are learning it is very important and necessary that you do the steps on your own. Trust me ;)

Comment: @imnoobcoder done. I think that it is the most agile and simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way you could approach this.

Nice and compact:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[] TBs = { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };
    TextBox tb = TBs.Where(x => !x.Visible).FirstOrDefault();
    if (tb != null) { tb.Visible = true; }
}
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` takes a predicate, no need for `Where`.

Comment: You're right, @Wyck, it does...but writing it that way has always just looked "weird" to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (!textBox3.Visible)
            { textBox3.Visible = true; return; }
            if(!textBox4.Visible)
            { textBox4.Visible = true; return; }
            if (!textBox5.Visible)
            { textBox5.Visible = true; return; }
            if (!textBox6.Visible)
            { textBox6.Visible = true; return; }
        }
```

Comment: your code is pretty perfect, yet I would suggest to use nested if else branches instead of returning out of the function in the if branch itself

Answer (score 0):

Example for my comment:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<TextBox> textBoxes;

    private int iterator = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBoxes = new List<TextBox>
            {
                this.textBox1,
                this.textBox3,
                this.textBox2,
                this.textBox4
            };
        this.textBoxes.ForEach(tb => tb.Visible = false);
    }

    private void buton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.iterator >= this.textBoxes.Count())
        {
            // Do something that you need, then all textboxes are visible

            return;
        }

        this.textBoxes[this.iterator++].Visible = true;
    }
}
```

In `ctor` you control the order of showing your `textbox`es by manipulating of them order in `textBoxes`.